# not finding a image path with express.static

Tags: node.js, express

here is the image file name saved -

```
 const newProduct = new ProductDB({
      imageFileName: url + '/images/' + req.file.filename,
 });
```

when i am trying to use the image in the front and now i am getting -

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/1628875244435-3564.png 404 (Not Found)
```

the network preview -

[image]

i tried to use express.static for getting the image -

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join('shop-backend/images')));
```

and i am still getting the same error.

Comment: have you checked the file has been uploaded and is in the correct path?, you have not mentioned any debugging you have done, note that your path.join with a single string is abit superfluous, it's just going to return `shop-backend/images` also adding the full url including schema and domain and port to imageFileName will cause issues when you want to go live, instead just use a filename, it's then flexible to be /images/* or /image/* or /foo/* etc, let the router handle virtual path

Comment: its the correct path.
can u add a code snippet i didnt understand exactly what u ment

Answer (score 0):

[Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Comment: still does now working, is there anything else might cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this steps:

1: app.use(express.static('public'))// provided you want it in the public dir

2: access your file without the dir such as "url +  req.file.filename"